# Book involving alien brothers who come to Earth and develop a relationship with a human girl

Tags: story-identification, novel, aliens

A few years ago I read a book and it’s really hard for me to remember all the details.

Basically, aliens came to Earth and I remember a human girl left with them. They were like alien princes and warriors and they were brothers who lived next to each other in some nice homes. She was living with the one alien that claimed her or something and I think he got her a dog or something. The brother had a party she went to and I think he almost kissed her. And there was a secret underground passageway.

The cover was like pink and purple and blue. I know this is a long shot, due to my terrible memory and description, but hopefully someone has read the book before.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, you mentioned that the human girl "left" with the alien brothers; where did they take her? To another planet, or just somewhere else on Earth?

Comment: Another user with the same username as yours has attempted to edit this question. If that person is you, you should use the same account you used to post this question to edit it; that way, you won't need to submit the edit for approval by other users for the edit to go through. You'll also be able to post comments here if you want to. If you've lost access to your previous account, you can have your new account merged with the old one by following the instructions provided [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).